# How can I use 'this' in defaultProps React.Component class syntax?

Tags: javascript, class, reactjs, ecmascript-6

In the past I was able to set a default prop that used `this` like so...

```
let MyButton = React.createClass({
    getDefaultProps() {
        return {
            buttonRef: (ref) => this.button = ref
        };
    },
```

But now that I'm using JS classes `MyButton` looks like this...

```
class MyButton extends React.Component {
    static defaultProps = {
        buttonRef: (ref) => this.button = ref
    };
```

And I get an error saying that `this` is undefined.

What do I need to do to be able to set default props that use `this`?

EDIT: Add some context

Setting a default `buttonRef` prop allowed me to use the ref in the `MyButton` component but also always be able to pass in a custom ref if a parent component needs to access the `MyButton` DOM node.

```
class MyButton extends React.Component {
    static defaultProps = {
        buttonRef: (ref) => this.button = ref
    };

    componentDidMount() {
        Ladda.bind(this.button);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <button
                ref={(ref) => this.button = this.props.buttonRef(ref)}
                onClick={this.props.handleClick}
            >
                {this.props.buttonText}
            </button>
        );
    }
}
```

So then my button can always get hooked in to Ladda: `Ladda.bind(this.button)`

And if I need to access that button's DOM node in a parent component I can do so by passing in `buttonRef` as a prop like...

```
class MouseOverButton extends React.Component {
    componentDidMount() {
        this.mouseEnterButton.addEventListener("mouseover", doSomething(event));
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <MyButton
                    buttonRef={(ref) => this.mouseEnterButton = ref}
                />
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

EDIT: Apparently my simplified example doesn't illustrate the point well enough so I can come up with a more practical example or y'all can just answer the original question: What do I need to do to be able to use `this` in my `defaultProps`?  Can I no longer do that using JS class syntax?

Where this convention of having a defaultProp for a specific element's ref has been useful is when using a HOC that hooks a nested component into some 3rd party API.  I have an `AddressSearch` HOC that takes a node via a function passed to the wrapped component. Then it uses that node to hook it up with Google's Places API.

So I've got my `addAddressSearch(component)` function from my HOC.  It adds the functions needed to hook up the Google places API.  But for Google's API to work I need to know what DOM node I'm working with. So I pass my `Input` component an `inputRef` that gives my `AddressSearchInput` access to the appropriate node.

```
class AddressSearchInput extends React.Component {
    static defaultProps = {
        inputRef: (ref) => this.addressSearchInput = ref
    };

    componentDidMount() {
        let node = this.addressSearchInput;

        this.props.mountAddressSearch(node);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <Input
                    inputAttributes={inputAttributes}
                    inputRef={(ref) => this.addressSearchInput = this.props.inputRef(ref)}
                    labelText={<span>Event address or venue name</span>}
                    labelClassName={labelClassName}
                />
            </div>
        );
    }
}

AddressSearchInput = addAddressSearch(AddressSearchInput);

module.exports = AddressSearchInput;

// Here's the Input component if that helps complete the picture here
class Input extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <Label>{this.props.labelText}</Label>
                <HelperText text={this.props.inputHelperText} />
                <input
                    {...this.props.inputAttributes}
                    ref={this.props.inputRef}
                ></input>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

So now when I want to use my `AddressSearchInput` in a parent component that needs to add an eventListener to the relevant node I can just pass `AddressSearchInput` an `inputRef` prop.

```
class VenueStreetAddress extends React.Component {
    componentDidMount() {
        let node = this.venueStreetAddressInput;
        this.props.mountValidateOnBlur(node, venueValidationsArray);
    },
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <AddressSearchInput
                    inputRef={(ref) => this.venueStreetAddressInput = ref}
                    hasError={this.props.hasError}
                />
                {this.props.errorMessageComponent}
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

And I can use `AddressSearchInput` all over the place and it doesn't break anything.

```
class UserStreetAddress extends React.Component {
    componentDidMount() {
        let node = this.userStreetAddressInput;
        this.props.mountValidateOnBlur(node, userValidationsArray);
    },
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <AddressSearchInput
                    inputRef={(ref) => this.userStreetAddressInput = ref}
                    hasError={this.props.hasError}
                />
                {this.props.errorMessageComponent}
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Maybe this way is convoluted and wrong but I don't have the time to figure out another way to do it on my own.  So either point me to a tutorial(s) on the best way to hook into 3rd party APIs and add dynamic form validation without using refs or answer my original question which is...

**What do I need to do to be able to use `this` in my `defaultProps`?  Can I no longer do that using JS class syntax?**

EDIT: In attempting to explain my use case I had the idea to make my defaultProps look like this...

```
static defaultProps = {
    inputRef: (ref) => ref
};
```

which seems to be working without error.

In any case, the original question still stands. **What do I need to do to be able to use `this` in my `defaultProps`?  Can I no longer do that using JS class syntax?**

Comment: `static` is a method on the class itself, not instances of the class. `this` refers to an instance of your MyButton class, hence this is not valid inside your static method. What you are trying to do seems strange - perhaps add some more context and we can help find an alternative approach.

Comment: This is hard to follow if I were to read the code, why don't you just pass down the `onMouseOver` event down to `MyButton`, you define the `doSomething` in the parent and then pass it down. Doing that `Ladda.bind` is unusual, why does Ladda need a reference to `this.button` ? I feel like if you need to do this then something is wrong in the way you are structuring your components.

Comment: You can access the child ref in the following manner https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44564565/reactjs-how-to-get-ref-of-a-component-whose-ref-comes-from-its-parent/44564745#44564745

Comment: This is not necessarily strange. Imagine you want to put a button inside your component that, when on clicked, removes the component itself. You could simply use `document.getElementById()` in your default prop, yes, but what if your component is rendered on the server? There's no `document` up there.

Answer (score 1):

This really should be a method, not a property.

```
class MyButton extends React.Component {
    setButtonRef (ref) {
        this.button = ref;
    }
    componentDidMount() {
        Ladda.bind(this.button);
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <button
                ref={ ref => this.setButtonRef(ref) }
                onClick={this.props.handleClick}
            >
                {this.props.buttonText}
            </button>
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want a ref to the button, bind a variable at the class level and assign it to that class variable. Example:

```
export default class MyComponent extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    // button will be available as `this.button`
  }

  button = null;  // initialize to null

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Button ref={e => { this.button = e; }} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since a static property has no knowledge of class instances, if it's strictly necessary to make a static method aware of a given instance, the only way would be to pass to the static method the instance as an argument:

```
<button
    ref={(ref) => this.button = this.props.buttonRef(this, ref)}
    onClick={this.props.handleClick}
>
```

And in your defaultProp, use the instance:

```
static defaultProps = {
    buttonRef: (instance, ref) => instance.button = ref
};
```